# another haskell IO issue

Tags: haskell, io

Ok, so let's say I have a function which takes a String and returns a certain value of that string specified by a text file. A text file will look like this.

> hello - 2
>      bye   - 3

so the function would return 2 given "hello" and 3 given "bye". Now, the function is of type Weight (I can't change it as this is the part of the framework):

```
type Weight = String -> Int
```

How do I implement such function given that it HAS TO be of the type Weight. The problem is that I don't know how to make weight aware of what value to return given a certain string. I can't hardcode the values because they will be different in different textfiles. And I can't have readFile inside the function or anything like that, right? Are there any other options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two choices,

```
assignWeight :: String -> IO Int
assignWeight = do
  file <- readFile whatever

  -- parse file and extract a function assigning strings to their weights
  return $ parseFile file
```

Or,

```
assignWeight :: String -> Weight
assignWeight file = parseFileAndExtractWeights file
```

and then read the file in `main` and use currying. So there's not toplevel function, but we still get our function later by partially applying `assignWeight` to the contents of the file

```
main = do
  weights <- assignWeight `fmap` readFile whatever
  -- use weights
```

But you can't perform IO in a computation of type `Weight`, so you'll either have to perform it elsewhere and pass the type to it or just change the type. No other way about it.

Comment: `readFile whatever >>= return . assignWeight` can be written as `assignWeight <$> readFile whatever`.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought. Unfortunately, none of these are satisfactory so I'll have to search for some workarounds. I just thought maybe you can simulate a global fixed variable somehow to hold contents of the file, since it does not change after the contents of the file are read. But I can't see the way to do this.

Comment: @user2922609 You can't. Haskell doesn't allow this sort of mutation

Comment: @user2922609: there is a way, and it can be safe provided that you know the files don't change after they're read.  But I'd think twice before doing it.  http://augustss.blogspot.com/2011/04/ugly-memoization-heres-problem-that-i.html

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have `assignWeight` globally, but you can have it locally with the genuine non-IO type you wanted. I think the approach below is a common pattern used to separate monadic code from non-monadic.

```
import Data.Maybe
import Control.Applicative

parseFile :: IO [(String, Int)]
parseFile = read <$> readFile "Parse.txt"

main = do
        content <- parseFile
        let assignWeight x = fromJust $ lookup x content
        print $ process assignWeight

type Weight = String -> Int

process :: Weight -> Int
process x = 0
```

Here `assignWeight` is of correct type. You can pass it around: look how I passed it to non-monadic `process` function. You cannot have `assignWeight` defined at top level without violating purity, as other commenters pointed out, but to have it locally and pass around is a commonly used approach.

Here is a more modular approach:

```
getAssignWeight :: IO Weight
getAssignWeight = do
        content <- parseFile
        let assignWeight x = fromJust $ lookup x content
        return assignWeight

main = do
        assignWeight <- getAssignWeight
        print $ process assignWeight
```